# Vite throw an error on the page after building project. (Vite + Vue + Laravel)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, build, vite

There is a project on Vite 3.0.0 + Vue 3 + Laravel 9. On the server vite throw an error on the page after building project. Ask if you need any more details.

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1600,
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

Locally and on the server, when you run `vite` (*npm run dev*) everything works, but when you run `vite build` (*npm run build*) on the server, vite throw an error on the page.

There are options what might be wrong?

server: http://intime.bestleasing.com.ua/

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Do you run the `start` script? Does it work locally? (in NON dev mode)